# Как поступит Java при компиляции?

Tags: логика, java, компиляция

Код:

```
int x = 1;
if (x != 2) { int y = 2;}
int z = x + y;
System.out.print(z);
```

Собственно говоря, этот код, несмотря на if, в любом случае эквивалентен этому:

```
System.out.print(3);
```

А теперь сам вопрос **Что запишет в скомпилированный файл java?** *Короткую* или *длинную* версию кода?

Comment: А вы откомпилируйте и посмотрите.

Comment: я думаю пропустит

Comment: Это не скомпилируется, переменная `y` не видна вне блока, разве нет?

Comment: А вообще, зависит от оптимизатора, конечно. И так и так правильно. Результат-то одинаковый?

Comment: Не думаю, что тут что-то будет принципиально изменено.

Хорошо оптимизируются выражения типа *а = 2 + 3*; Ну... возможно ещё подряд при определении. Выкидывать операторы - не думаю.

Comment: @SilverIce: вы не поверите, как много может выкинуть хороший оптимизатор. У меня gcc выбрасывал целые классы и вызовы виртуальных функций. (Язык был, правда, C++.)

Comment: @VladD

Нет, ну почему же - охотно поверю. Выкидываются неиспользуемые функции, классы и переменные. Насчет виртуальных функций... не уверен, честно говоря. Это в С++ довольно жесткая типизация данных, а Java с её наследованиями и объектной моделью - не факт. Хотя, возможно, если хорошо поиграться с указателями, то и С++ побоиться удалять "лишние" функции)))

Comment: Как показала проверка, Java-compiler иерархию и методы не трогает. По крайней мере по-умолчанию... 

Ну... С есть С, что тут ещё скажешь))

Comment: @SilverIce: может, у вас недостаточно агрессивные настройки оптимизации? Хотя, может быть, главная оптимизация происходит на этапе JIT.

Comment: IMHO в любом случае в строке

    int z = x + y;

`y` не существует.

В первом комментарии @VladD правильно написал - Не скомпилируется.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Маленький эксперимет.

**Вариант 1**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 0;
        if (x != 2) { y = 2;}
        int z = x + y;
        System.out.print(z);
    }
```

Никаких изменений. 1 в 1.

**Вариант 2**

Исходник:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int x = 1 + 4;
    int y = 0 + x;
    if (x != 2) y = 2;
    int z = x + y - y + y - x + x;
    System.out.print(z);
}
```

декомпиляция:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 0 + x;
    if (x != 2) y = 2;
    int z = x + y - y + y - x + x;
    System.out.print(z);
}
```

Как и ожидалось, ушло только очевидное сложение.

**Вариант 3**

А вот с константами всё интереснее:

Исходник:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int x = 1 + 4;
    final int y = 1 + x;
    final int z = x + y - y + y - x + x;
    System.out.print(z);
}
```

Декомпиляция:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   int x = 5;
   int y = 6;
   int z = 11;
   System.out.print(11);
}
```

Вот тут уже оптимизатор оттянулся как захотел)

Инструменты JDK 1.7.0.9 + JD 0.6.2

Comment: не поленился =) молодец

Comment: Cтранно, что оптимизатор вообще оставил x, y и z.

Comment: Лучше в таком случае, наверно, на байткод смотреть, а не на результат связки компилятор + декомпилятор.

Comment: @Котик: в .NET, ЕМНИМС, большая часть оптимизации производится jitter'ом. Может, и в Java так же?

Comment: @VladD

- Просто ОП спрашивал про результат работы компилятора, а мой комментарий был про то, что реальный байткод, полученный с помощью `javac,` может не соответствовать тому, что получится, если по этому байткоду пройтись с помощью `JD.`

- Как я понимаю, разговор о микрооптимизациях в `managed` языках с `JIT'`ом - довольно бессмысленная затея :)

Comment: @Котик: угу. Особенно если учесть, что jit-оптимизатор для выбора своих параметров руководствуется некими статистическими данными о том, какие ветки кода более важны, скоростью процессора, направлением ветра и фазой луны.